# R: regexpr failed?

Tags: r, regex, regexp-replace

I don't understand why the syntax failed to work. Why it can find string "10-year", and string "(342)" but not "10-year(342)"? (I assume when it returns -1, it means can't find it) What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

`pos = regexpr('10-year(342)', '<td class="sente">10-year(342)<td class="sente">')`

[image]

Comment: Parens are special characters in a regular expression. If you want to look for literal parens, you need to escape them, e.g `'10-year\\(342\\)`. But the real solution here is probably to not use regular expressions on html, but instead to use an actual html/xml parser.

Comment: Thanks, I did read "Any metacharacter with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash. " from stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html, but it didn't say double backslashes...

Comment: Yes, it can be a bit confusing. Note that "\" is itself listed as a special character, which means, by recursion, that to get an _actual_ backslash you actually need two "\\".

Comment: You can also use `fixed = TRUE` if you're trying to match an entire string with no special regex characters that you need interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The round brackets in your expression are interpreted. You should escape them like so:

```
regexpr('10-year\\(342\\)', '<td class="sente">10-year(342)<td class="sente">')
```

Comment: Thanks, I did read "Any metacharacter with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash. " from https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html, but it didn't say double backslashes...